# $(a_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence of integers

Tags: real-analysis

When we say a Convergent Sequence in Set of Integers ? 
does this implies that the limit of  $(a_n)_n$ is an integer ? why?
I konw that the sequence reaches some value in $\mathbb{Z}$ and stays there (but I don't want to use it. ) I'm wondering if the limit of $(a_n)$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$.?

Comment: Yes. See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convergent_Sequence_in_Set_of_Integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with the discrete topology, then every non trivial sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$ of integers is divergent. Indeed, if the opposite occurs, one can find a real $a$ such that, for every $\epsilon >0$, there is a natural $n_0$ such that $|a_n -a|<\epsilon$, for $n\geq n_0$; setting $\epsilon=1/2$ you get an absurd. In the trivial case, the sequence converges to a integer. Thus, a sequence of integers is convergent iff is trivial.

Is not hard to show that, if $\langle a_n\rangle$ is monotonous and no trivial, then $a_n \to\infty$, in the crescent case, or $a_n\to-\infty$ in the decreasing case. Indeed, if $\langle a_n\rangle$ is crescent, then for every $M>0$, there is a natural $n_0$ such that, for every $n\geq n_0$, $a_n>M$.

Comment: Trivial sequence means a sequence that is constant after some point.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we observe your sequence in a [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) $\mathbb{R}$. Then yes, if the limit exists, it's an integer.

Suppose it exists, but it isn't an integer. Let's denote it by $L$ and take $\varepsilon  = \frac{1}{2}\min \left\{ {\left\lceil L \right\rceil  - L,L - \left\lfloor L \right\rfloor } \right\}$. Since $L$ isn't an integer, $\varepsilon  > 0$. Furthermore, $\left| {L - {a_n}} \right| \geqslant \varepsilon ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, which is a contradiction with the assumption that $L$ is the limit of the sequence in question.

So, $L$ must be an integer if it exists.

$\left\lceil x \right\rceil $ is the ceiling of $x$, the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$. Similarly, $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor $ is the floor of $x$.

Comment: It's a set equipped with a function, called metric, which tells you what is a distance between its elements. For example, a natural metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is $d\left( {x,y} \right) = \left| {y - x} \right|$, which tells you how far are real numbers $x$ and $y$ from each other.

Comment: Suppose the limit is 0.6. Ceiling of 0.6 is the smallest integer greater then 0.6, which is 1. So the smallest integer greater than 0.6 has a distance at least 1-0.6=0.4 from the limit. Similarly, the greatest integer smaller than the limit has a distance at least 0.6-0=0.6. Intuitively, the ceiling and the floor are the best candidates for the limit, but even they are not sufficiently close